# What is the bootstrap.sh script?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to install cabal-install. `Readme` says I should use `bootstrap.sh` to `download and install the dependencies`. It says I should use this script like below

```
$ ./bootstrap.sh
```

But I couldn't find such script in `/`

So, the question is, what is the `bootstrap.sh` script, what is its purpose and where to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not in `/`, it's in your current working directory when  you run the command. All directories have an implied `.` directory in them, which references the directory itself.

Thus, `./bootstrap.sh` is in your working directory.

It's purpose is as described, to "download and install the dependencies".

You should be able to find it where the `Readme` file is or somewhere else in the file you downloaded (and maybe extracted).